# Puppet: write a repo resource but include it in multiple places without duplication

Tags: deployment, puppet

I'm writing a puppet module for my application, and from some days I'm stuck on how to manage the repo.

I have **puppet 4.10** and all the nodes are **Centos 7**

The *init.pp* file in the module of my application is:

```
 class my_app{
   anchor { '::my_app::begin': } ->
   class { '::my_app::repo': } ->
   class { '::my_app::install': } ->
   class { '::my_app::config': } ->
   class { '::my_app::service': } ->
   anchor { '::my_app::end': }
}
```

and the *repo.pp* class is:

```
class my_app::repo{
  if ! defined(Yumrepo[my_app]) {
    yumrepo {'my_app' :
      ensure   => 'present',
      descr    => 'my_app RPM repository',
      baseurl  => 'http://my_repo_server.com/repos/my_app',
      gpgcheck => 0
    }
  }
}
```

The *init.pp* class is installed on all the servers, now the problem is that all the clients and maybe also some servers needs also to have the *my_app_client.pp*:

```
class my_app::my_app_client{
  include my_app::repo
  [...]
}
```

The code returns an error *is already declared* because I declared the class *my_app::repo* twice.

I don't think that define 2 repo definitions in this case is correct, and declare it as *Defined Resource Types* doesn't seem to work either.

How should I resolve this issue? What is the good practice in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have somehow misrepresented your situation, because Puppet classes are idempotent.  Declaring the same class more than once has no additional effect over declaring it just once.  The main piece of the solution to the type of problem you have is generally to do what you are already doing: put the resource declaration into a class, and obtain it (only) via that class.

Comment: I'm inclined to guess, therefore, that in fact you do have a duplicate declaration somewhere, presumably in one of your other classes.  If you think differently, then we'll need to see a [mcve] to help you sort it out.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I can't include the class `my_app::repo` because puppet will complain with the error: 

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Class[My_app::Repo] is already declared; cannot redeclare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't use

```
class { '::my_app::repo': }
```

and

```
include my_app::repo
```

in the same set of manifests.

The documentation for this is at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_classes.html#declaring-classes. The upshot is that you can only use a resource-like declaration (so, `class`) once for each class and you can't mix it with `include`, but you can `include` a class as many times as you like.

In your case, I'd suggest you refactor to use `include` throughout for your `my_app` classes.

Comment: Following your suggestion I changed `class { '::my_app::repo': }` with the include on the top of the class and I kept the dependency in the anchor with `Class['my_app::repo'] ->`. It works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: This is a good observation, but not quite correct.  You *can* use resource-like and include-like declarations of the same class in the same manifest set.  Moreover, if there are multiple declarations of the same class then it is not sufficient to simply choose one form or the other.  The actual rule is that if there are multiple declarations of the same class, then only the first one to be evaluated can have resource-like form.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation, however. I frequently recommend that the include-like forms be strongly preferred, and this is why.  If used at all, the resource-like form should be limited to classes declaring private classes from their own module, under conditions where they can ensure that supported usage of public module classes cannot run into this duplicate class declaration issue.